# NSIS Multiple components option

Tags: nsis, nsis-mui

I am a newbie in NSIS. I need some help regarding the MUI Components page. I am adding 3 section Group and different sections inside the Section Groups. I need to do different actions based on the user selection. Users have the options to select multiple options.
So can anyone please help me with a sample code which is having more than 3 sections and verifying the user selection of those options and based on that displaying different message boxes

Comment: You just do the normal stuff in the sections and they get run if they're selected... if that's not all you're asking about, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very unclear to me what your real goal is but checking section states can be done like this:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

page components
page instfiles

SectionGroup /e "Group 1"
Section "G1S1" SEC_G1S1
SectionEnd
Section /o "G1S2" SEC_G1S2
SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd

SectionGroup /e "Group 2"
Section /o "G2S1" SEC_G2S1
SectionEnd
Section "G2S2" SEC_G2S2
SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd

Section -Hidden
${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC_G1S1}
    MessageBox mb_ok "G1S1 is selected"
${EndIf}
${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC_G1S2}
    MessageBox mb_ok "G1S2 is selected"
${EndIf}
# Check the other sections here ...
SectionEnd
```